# vimrun.exe not found in your $PATH

Tags: vim, plugins, vundle

I recently got vim and have been trying to install some plugins. I installed vim as a plugin manager. I entered some plugins in the _vimrc file just like you are supposed to.
Example: `Plugin 'scroolose/nerdtree'`
But, when I did `:PluginInstall` I got a popup saying "vimrun.exe not found in your $PATH". I found the vimrun.exe file and it *was not* in the right place so I moved it to the vimfiles folder and then the bundle folder and then the Vundle.vim folder I always got the same popup.

After getting the popup message the plugins never install properly. I always get a bunch of errors as vim tries to process the plugins and then at the end it says "done!". When I try using the plugins it never works and it seems like the plugins never got installed.

If you could also help me with [my vim syntax problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193672/e484-cant-open-file-c-users-me-desktop-syntax-syntax-vim-using-vundle), that would be great.(only if you wish to)>

Comment: This is a question for Vundle's issue tracker.

Comment: What is that? Where can I get an answer?